# No sé por qué este código es erróneo

Tags: python

```
# Se trata de una función donde con una lista de cadenas has de transformar las 
#cadenas pares en claves y las impares en valores en un diccionario.

def toDictionary(s):
    result = {}
    k = ""
    v = ""
    i = 0
    if len(s) == 0:
        return {}
    else:
        for c in s:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                k = c
            else:
                v = c
                result[k] = v
            i += 1
    return result
```

Comment: Y cual es el error? Modifica tu pregunta añadiéndolo.

Comment: que no me funciona pero no sé cual especificamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El código es correcto y hace lo que se espera de él si la lista tiene un número par de elementos.

Si el número de elementos es impar, hace algo razonable, y es que considera sólo los primeros N-1 elementos (descartando el "sobrante" al final). No obstante, tal vez no cumpla la especificación para este último caso, pero en tu enunciado no hay nada que prohiba este comportamiento.

No obstante, aunque funciona, el estilo se puede mejorar.

Por ejemplo, puedes eliminar el primer `else:` ya que si la lista está vacía hará un `return` y abandonará la función, y si no está vacía continuará haciendo el resto de la función, que por tanto puede ir fuera del `else`, reduciendo la indentación necesaria en el código:

```
def toDictionary(s):
    result = {}
    k = ""
    v = ""
    i = 0
    if len(s) == 0:
        return {}
    for c in s:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            k = c
        else:
            v = c
            result[k] = v
        i += 1
    return result
```

Esto no es puramente estético, también lo hace más fácil de leer al reducir su [complejidad ciclomática](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complejidad_ciclom%C3%A1tica)

Es más, el `if` completo sobra, ya que si la lista está vacía no llegará a iterar ninguna vez en el `for`, y por tanto retornará lo que había en `resultado`, que ya era una lista vacía. También sobra la inicialización de las variables `k` y `v`. No importa qué valor inicial tengan porque en el bucle les cambiarás ese valor de todas formas. Así que:

```
def toDictionary(s):
    result = {}
    i = 0
    for c in s:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            k = c
        else:
            v = c
            result[k] = v
        i += 1
    return result
```

Finalmente, para evitar la inicialización e incremento de `i`, puedes hacer uso de la función python `enumerate()`. A esta función le pasas una lista y te devuelve un iterador sobre el que puedes hacer `for`. Cada vez que iteres obtendrás dos datos: el primero será un entero que es el índice del elemento. El segundo será el valor del elemento. Usando este truco:

```
def toDictionary(s):
    result = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            k = c
        else:
            v = c
            result[k] = v
    return result
```

El código ha ganado en legibilidad y simplicidad, pero desde el punto de vista funcional es equivalente al tuyo, y producirá los mismos resultados, por lo que seguramente seguirá siendo inválido. Hasta que no esté más clara la especificación del problema y un ejemplo de un caso en que falle, no podemos ayudarte más.

### Edición

Un último truco (pero funcionalmente sigue siendo equivalente). Si usas `s[::2]` puedes obtener los elementos pares de la lista, y si usas `s[1::2]` los elementos impares, pues el operador de *slice* admite un tercer valor para el "paso" entre elementos. Si combinas ambos resultados con `zip()`, puedes ir obteniendo parejas de clave y valor:

```
def toDictionary(s):
    result = {}
    for k, v in zip(s[::2],s[1::2]):
        result[k] = v
    return result
```

No creo que ganemos mucho en legibilidad haciéndolo así, pero pensé que podría interesarte conocer este truco para otras ocasiones.

Y ya puestos, si nos dejamos llevar por la fiebre del "dejarlo en una línea" (es una fiebre contagiosa y no siempre deseable...) puedes usar la sintaxis de *dict comprehension*:

```
def toDictionary(s):
    return {k: v for k,v in zip(s[::2],s[1::2])}
```

Sigue dando los mismos resultados que tu función original.